# how to create clickable links on impress.js?

Tags: css, impress.js

I am trying to create a brochure visual treat for a client using impress.js
I need to put a link on every slide that redirect to the proper page while click. 
Is it possible that each page could also have a click able link to every slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jimpress.js](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/) to achieve that and take also advantage of the numerous other options that this plugin provides.

Comment: Thank u for the reply.
I've found that we can use it as usual anchor tag and link like

**bold**<a href='/'><img src="imagepath"></a>**bold**

but jimpress.js supports IE8 and 7.